# IAIK toolkit for android

Tags: android, ios, cryptography, pkcs#12, iaik-jce

I have an web application that does the signing using IAIK framework which is purely java based framework.The keystore is of type PKCS#12.
In web application I am using applets to do the signing.

Our New requirement is to create a mobile app to do the signing process with IAIK framework and also should be able to create PKCS#12 keystore using IAIK framework.

So my question is can I create an mobile app(Android/IOS) and use the same IAIK framework to do the signing and keystore creation.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Create a small test application that uses the IAIK libraries and try it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just one doubt. After signing we sends data to server to verify. Our server resides in Intranet network. Since I have no idea about android/ios app. So is it possible from android/ios app to connect or send data to server that resides in intranet network.

Comment: Android is very different from iOS, though both have full-featured operating systems with complete networking capabilities comparable to desktop systems. Android is Java based, so porting a Java-based code base to it should be easier than trying to port something to iOS.

Comment: Yes for android we can port java code base. But we need to support for IOS also and may be windows phone too. So can those java code base can be port for IOS/windows phone?. I have heard of hybrid app that will wok for android/ios/windows, not sure on this part.

Comment: For the crypto I would strongly suggest to define an OS independent protocol and implement it using the capabilities of each platform. If required you could define a high level API on top of that.